# Why is my print function printing the () and the "" along with the statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, printing

*This is my code for a challenge in Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner*

```
    food = input("What is your favorite entree? ")

    dessert = input("What is your favorite dessert? ")

    print("\nI am going to assume that your favorite meal is" , food +   dessert)
```

*Instead of printing*

```
I am going to assume that your favorite meal is
```

*It is printing*

```
('\nI am going to assume that your favorite meal is', 'steakcookies')
```

*What do I need to change?*

Comment: `print` isn't a function, you don't put parentheses around the argument. So the parentheses are creating a list, and it's printing the list.

Comment: @Barmar: A tuple, not a list.

Comment: Usually we see the opposite question - people try to use the Python 2 syntax on Python 3 and get confused by the SyntaxError.

Comment: In python 2.7, when you use print(some, text, here), it prints a tuple with some, text and here as the members of the tuple. You can fix this by not using the parenthese, so:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are treating it like Python 3's `print()` function. When you do this in Python 2, it prints the object you give it, which is a `tuple`. In Python 3, those parentheses would delineate the function call, with each contained object being an argument passed to the function.

If you want it to behave the way you expect, import the `print()` function at the top of your code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

From that point onward in that program, `print` will refer to the function, not the statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take out the parentheses:

```
print "\nI am going to assume that your favorite meal is" , food +   dessert
```

In Python2, `print` is a statement, not a function.  When you include the parentheses, `print` treats the arguments as part of a tuple.  You should also be using `raw_input()`, not `input()`.  Alternatively, put `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning of the file.